# Is there something equivalent to switch case in microsoft excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have to prepare an inventory sheet of my products. So I have three sizes, Small, Medium and Large. The details we receive from our supplier consists of a column consisting of abbreviated sizes S/M/L. But I prepare my version of the sheet with Small/Medium/Large.

So how do I simply check if:

```
case "S": Small
case "M": Medium
case "L": "Large"
default
```

Comment: Create a table with the lookup values and use `VLOOKUP()`.

Comment: CHOOSE ain't a bad alternative, but the implied case labels are consecutive from 1. (And there's no follow through).

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this.  Various lookups, nested IF's, etc.  What have you tried and where have you run into problems? Best way depends on info you haven't provided. Please read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: VLOOKUP() is good but some cells (in the size column of vendor file) are blank so vlookup generate #N/A for those cells. That is undesirable.

Comment: Nested IF's can get complicated. Maybe not for size chart. But we have color code table. It has 25 colors. Can't use Nested-IF :(

Comment: In your question you only showed three codes.  But you can certainly use a lookup table for the color codes.  What have you tried? Where have you run into problems.  Your failure to show any of this is why your question is receiving `close` votes.

Comment: @rhlchd In addition, there are solutions for your `#NA` problem. Again, I suggest you read the HELP topics I mentioned, and edit your question to provide useful information to which we can offer help.

Answer (score 1):

Excel introduced a [new SWITCH function](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/excel-case-statement-switch-function/) that basically is of the form `=SWITCH(Expression, value1, result1, value2, result2.....)`. It should help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Case sizeString
    Case Is = "S"
        Size = "Small"
    Case Is = "M"
        Size = "Medium"
    Case Is = "L"
        Size = "Large"
    Case Else
        MsgBox ("There was an error with sizeString- did not contain an expected value.")
End Select
```

-TheSilkCode

Comment: I suggest mentioning that this code is VBA, since the original question did not carry a VBA tag.

Comment: @rhlchd , were you looking for an excel solution? I am sorry if I missed that-

Comment: It's alright @TheSilkCode, appreciate the effort :)

Comment: @rhlchd , apologies- do you want it in excel? some of the posters above have mentioned how I would do it but happy to see what I come up with if you still need the help. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Select the relevant column (here `A` assumed) and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=A1="S"
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, Number, Category: `Custom`, Type: `@"mall"`, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Then add rules in a similar way for "M" and "L".

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft replace SWITCH, IFS and IFVALUES with CHOOSE only function. `=CHOOSE($L$1,"index_1","Index_2","Index_3")`

L1 must be equal to some index number part of series.

Answer (score 0):

Since Excel 2016, this would be solved easily with SWITCH. But recently I had to work with Excel 2010 again for a while and there is no SWITCH function there. Using your example, here is a solution that does not use SWITCH:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(SUM((A1={"S";"M";"L"})*ROW(INDIRECT(1&":"&3))),"SMALL","MEDIUM","LARGE"),"else case")
```

Since it is an array formula, you have to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to make it work.

Here is how it works:

- Cond={"c1";"c2";...;"cn"} returns a N-vector of TRUE or FALSE (with behaves like 1s and 0s)
- ROW(INDIRECT(1&":"&n)) returns a N-vector of ordered numbers: 1;2;3;...;n
- The multiplication of both vectors will return lots of zeros and a number (position) where the condition was matched
- SUM just transforms this vector with zeros and a position into just a single number, which CHOOSE then can use
- If you want to add another condition, just remember to increment the last number inside INDIRECT
- The formula will not behave properly if you provide the same condition more than once, but I guess nobody would want to do that anyway